# Using instance method with variable #[]

Tags: chef-infra

I have [this method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Node#[]-instance_method) I need to use.

```
#[](attrib) ⇒ Object
Return an attribute of this node.
```

I can use it like this, which works fine:

```
# Create node instance and print specific attribute
node = Chef::Node.load("mynode22.zz.mysite.com")
puts node["my"]["application"]["version"]
```

But I’m trying to run this in a loop so I need the `["my"]["application"]["version"]` part to be passed in as a variable.
Below, `attr` would be assigned to `["my"]["application"]["version"]`

```
attributes.each do |attr|
    puts node#{attr}
end
```

But that doesn’t work. Anyone know how I can use a variable in this case? I am still learning Ruby and I’m stuck on this one.

Comment: What context is this in? We don't really recommend using the Chef gem as a library.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that keeps calling the `#[]` method on the return value of the previous call, if it returns anything:

```
def nested_accessor(object, *keys)
  keys.reduce(object) do |current, key|
    current[key] if current
  end
end
```

and then you could call that method such as:

```
class Node
  def initialize
    @attributes = {
      'my' => {
        'application' => {
          'version' => '0.0.1',
          'name' => 'Test App'
        },
        'config' => {
          'key' => 'value'
        }
      }
    }
  end

  def [](attrib)
    @attributes[attrib]
  end
end

node = Node.new
nested_accessor(node, 'my', 'application', 'version') # => "0.0.1"
nested_accessor(node, 'my', 'config') # => {"key"=>"value"}
nested_accessor(node, 'someone elses', 'application', 'version') # => nil
```

if you have the keys you want in an array already, you'll just need to splat the array in the parameter list:

```
nested_accessor(node, *['my', 'application', 'version'])
```

The `nested_accessor` method will work on any object, so long as that object and each object returned from a call to `#[]` respond to the `#[]` method or are `nil` (or `false`).

---

Just as an aside, Ruby has a method on [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) and [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-dig) called `dig`, that does something similar to this, it'll keep calling `dig` on each intermediate step until `nil` is returned or it has no more keys it needs to check. I'd recommend that method usually, but since this is a custom object, that does not seem to have a `dig` method, I created a pseudo-dig method (above), that works on `#[]` instead of `#dig`

Comment: You could also add this as an instance method to `Chef::Node` if you prefer, and not need the `object` parameter (using `self` instead), more object oriented, but depending on how many places this gets used, I personally don't like add methods to classes from gems to use in a single place in my code.

Comment: This is correct for general Ruby, but Chef has some more specific use cases. the `node` object looks kind of like a Hash but it very much is not.